# I would like to use conditional formatting with references to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In a sheet of a Sheet doc, I would like to use conditional formatting :

Which applies to my sheet1, range E8: UH49 Custom formula: = OR (COUNTIF (Holiday1; E5); COUNTIF(Holiday2; E5)) With Holiday1 and Holiday2 being named ranges in another sheet (sheet2 ) 
I tried with range name, and with the reference to the sheet name sheet2! ... the formula doesn't tell me anything invalid, but the conditional formatting doesn't work.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Welcome. Questions in this site should be posted in English.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to replace the original text for its translation to English.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting custom formula requires that the references be on the same sheet. To grab values from other sheets you could use INDIRECT.

Related

- [Conditional formatting across sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/62909/88163)
- [How to apply a relative reference in conditional formatting formula?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105390/88163)
- [Highlight Rows with Unique Values As Compared to Rows with Same ID# on a Different Sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117711/88163)